# MikroTik Capsman is trying to push network channel configurations that are not allowed by access points

Tags: networking, wifi, mikrotik, routeros

According to information from `allowed-channels` command on my Access Point the allowed channels are the following:

```
5180/20-Ceee/ac,
5260/20-Ceee/ac/DP,
5745/20-Ceee/ac,
5750/20-Ceee/ac,
5755/20-Ceee/ac,
5760/20-Ceee/ac,
5765/20-Ceee/ac
```

Despite the above, the manager insists on assigning frequencies outside of this range. It's not obvious at first but sometimes in logs I can find something like this:

```
cap7: failed to select channel, no supported channel
cap7: failed to select channel, no supported channel
cap8: failed to select channel, no supported channel
cap1: selected channel 5300/20-eeCe/ac/DP(23dBm)
```

`5300/20-eeCe/ac/DP` is being selected like 90% of time. Very rarely it selects something else... which is also unsupported anyway.

It looks like no matter what I do with the configuration on the Caps manager, the manager is trying to provision configuration that I didn’t even define.
You can see that in my configuration I explicitly defined only the frequencies allowed by the access point. I have also explicitly set `hw-supported-modes` to make sure that 5G config will go only to 5G interface. The configuration itself is extremely simple:

```
/caps-man channel
add band=5ghz-onlyac control-channel-width=20mhz extension-channel=Ceee frequency=5180,5260,5745,5750,5755,5760,5765 name=5G-20-Ceee
add band=2ghz-g/n control-channel-width=20mhz extension-channel=Ce frequency=2412,2417,2422,2427,2432,2437,2442 name=2G-20-Ce
/caps-man datapath
add bridge=bridge1 client-to-client-forwarding=yes local-forwarding=yes name=datapath1
/caps-man security
add authentication-types=wpa-psk,wpa2-psk name="The LAN" passphrase=*************
/caps-man configuration
add channel=5G-20-Ceee comment="5G Only" datapath=datapath1 mode=ap name="The LAN11" security="The LAN" ssid="The LAN11"
add channel=2G-20-Ce comment="2G only" datapath=datapath1 mode=ap name="The LAN2" security="The LAN" ssid="The LAN2"
/caps-man provisioning
add action=create-dynamic-enabled comment="5G only" hw-supported-modes=ac master-configuration="The LAN11" name-format=identity
add action=create-dynamic-enabled comment="2G only" hw-supported-modes=gn master-configuration="The LAN2" name-format=identity
```

Despite the above configuration, the manager completely ignores channels configuration and selects something different

[image: Wrong configuration error 1]
[image: Wrong configuration error 2]

Which in the end looks like the reason why the access point is unable to setup wireless interface correctly.
And this is a screenshot from the access point itself. You can see that the interfaces configuration is bogus and has nothing to do with the configuration that I’ve set on the manager:

[image: Wrong channel and missing SSID]

You can see that interface is disabled nad there is no SSID - this is the symptom of provisioning channel out of allowed range.

[image: Bogus config on AP]

I'm using 6.43.8 version of RouterOS (which is the latest one as of writing) with the following devices: hEX PoE Lite as router and capstan manager and multiple cAP ac access points.

I tried various different setups, disabled everything apart from basics to isolate the issue. MikroTik support responded with some general copy-paste answer and asked me to set `hw-supported-modes` which I did despite the fact that initially I was testing with only one interface.

Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug in RouterOS?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the "country" parameter is different between your AP and Capsman. Try setting the country explicitly in the Capsman configuration.